# Auto click popups in Access

Tags: ms-access, popup

I've just finished an Access database that auto backs up and archives itself, however it can't do it unless i'm there to click "Ok" on numerous popup windows.

Is there a way to bypass these popups as i would ideally like to run the backup at a time when no one is around (01:00 am) so no one could click the buttons and ultimately it would backup the database without user input.

I appreciate any help that is given

************Update************

I have figured out how to stop the majority of popups, the one that is tripping me up now is when it comes to saving the exported data.

It exports the data and saves it as PECData.xls but what i need it to do is overwrite the existing file that's in the folder without prompting for assurance to overwrite the existing file.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Post your code and we can take a look. It's more efficient than a dozen comments asking and confirming you've tried different commands.

Comment: You can use `Kill` to delete the previous file before exporting again. But I am sure there are also options to suppress the overwrite confirmation, depending on how you export your file.